# method range of object _worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I created a ActiveX button and write below code on click....but here I am facing an "method range of object _worksheet" error at line no. 2 when click on button.

```
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Range("Query1[#Headers]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Range("H15").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh   
    Range("Query2[#Headers]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

For an ActiveX object, the code will be in a worksheet module. In such a module, any Range/Cells call will refer to the sheet containing the code unless you specify otherwise, which you haven't here. In any event there is no need to select or activate here:

```
Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("Query1").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh   
    Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Query2").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```